# Python logging everything daily in file

Tags: python, logging, discord

I'm trying to understand the python logging module and am currently running into an issue. I'm adding lines to my own code to log to a file, but I'm using the discord bot module that also outputs data to the console.
**I'd like to log both my own stuff and the module logs to a file, creating a new file every day.**

I can output my own logs to a file using the TimedRotatingFileHandler, then add that same filename to basicConfig, but then my own logs get into the file 2x for each log action I do.
I can also get everything to log to the file in basicConfig, but I have no idea how to create a TimedRotationFileHandler to that, so I don't know how to make a log file for each day using that method.

Anyone who can help me out with this? Thanks a bunch!

````
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

def createLog(name):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename=name, filemode="a", format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    logfile = logging.getLogger(name)
    if (logfile.hasHandlers()):
        logfile.handlers.clear()
    else:
        print("No handlers")
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(name, when="midnight", interval=1)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.suffix = "%Y%m%d"
    logfile.addHandler(handler)
    logfile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logfile```
````

Comment: I'd try removing the filename and filemode arguments in the call to basicConfig.  Or if those arguments are required then maybe you can't call basicConfig.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks for your reply! That results in only output to the console. Only my own logcomment wil go to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOG_DIR_NAME = {log file name}
MAX_DAYS = { maximum number of days }
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(lineno)3d | %(levelname)5s | %(message)s')
logHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_DIR_NAME + logfile_name, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=MAX_DAYS)
```

Hope it will be helpful to you
or you can also check this answer[Python: How to create log file everyday using logging module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718204/python-how-to-create-log-file-everyday-using-logging-module)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can use this, but this only logs my own log-comments. The console output for the 'Discord' module will only output to console this way and won't end up in the log file.